# Accidental Pointer Reassignment in AVR Simulator

Tags: c, pointers, struct, microcontroller, avr

The following function, populateArpeggioArray, takes a pointer to a typedef'd struct containing several members, the identities of which are not necessarily relevant to the issue that I have. populateArpeggioArray should perform a few operations on the internal elements of the structure before passing a pointer to the struct to the function sortNoteStack.

What I've found is that the struct is never operated upon by sortNoteStack, because populateArpeggioArray, at some point, changes the value of the pointer to the struct before passing the changed value to sortNoteStack.

As far as I can tell, the code seems to be formatted properly, with proper pointer dereferencing for all operations performed on the elements of the struct. From what I can see, none of the lines of code should be able to modify the value of the pointer to the struct. Declaring the struct with the const prefix does not help, as its members are therefore also locked to a fixed value.

I'm open to the idea that this may be a problem with the simulator, and not the code, but if there is some latent issue with the code I have written, I'd certainly like to understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thank you for your help.

-Nick

```
void populateArpeggioArray(arpeggio* arp) {
        uint8_t i = 0,j=0, newNoteFlag=0;

        for(i=0; i<12; i++) {
            newNoteFlag = 0;
            if(globals.keyboardCurrentState[i]) {                                   /* Check to see if the current state shows that a keyboard button is pressed. */
                arp->sequenceLength++;                                              /* Temporarily increase the sequence length */
                for(j=0;j < arp->sequenceLength;j++) {                              /* Check the pitch of each note currently in the note stack */
                    if(globals.keyboardNotes[i] == arp->notesUnordered[j].pitch) {  /* If the currently selected note is already present in the note stack, */
                        arp->sequenceLength--;  
                        newNoteFlag = 1;                                            /* undo the temporary sequence length increase */
                    }           
                }   
                if(!newNoteFlag) {
                    arp->notesOrdered[arp->sequenceLength].pitch = globals.keyboardNotes[i]+liveArpeggio.transposeShift;
                    arp->notesUnordered[arp->sequenceLength].pitch = globals.keyboardNotes[i]+liveArpeggio.transposeShift;      /* Add the new pitch to the appended note */
                    arp->notesOrdered[arp->sequenceLength].length = 111;
                    arp->notesUnordered[arp->sequenceLength].length = 111;                          /* Give the new note a default length. TEMP */
                }
            }           
        }   
        sortNoteStack(&arp);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sortNoteStack(&arp)`, you're passing the address of the pointer, not the address of the struct. You want to pass the address of the struct (the value of the pointer). Thus, use `sortNoteStack(arp)`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that; I must have looked through the function 200 times. Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: Haha, it's always the little things that break everything. Happy coding!